# Why does Enumerable.Range get iterated twice?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am aware that `IEnumerable` is lazy, but I don't understand why `Enumerable.Range` gets iterated twice here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static int GetOne(int i)
        {
            return i / 2;
        }

        static IEnumerable<int> GetAll(int n)
        {
            var items = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select((i) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("getting item: " + i);
                return GetOne(i);
            });

            var data = items.Select(item => item * 2);

            // data.Count does NOT causes another re-iteration 
            Console.WriteLine("first: items: " + data.Count());
            return data;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            var data = GetAll(3);

            // data.Count DOES cause another re-iteration 
            Console.WriteLine("second: items: " + data.Count());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
getting item: 0
getting item: 1
getting item: 2
first: items: 3
getting item: 0
getting item: 1
getting item: 2
second: items: 3
```

Why does it not get re-iterated in "first" case, but does in the "second"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are triggering a re-iteration on `Count` (which in order to supply the answer requires a full iteration of the source). An `IEnumerable` will never keep hold of it's values and will always re-iterate when it needs to.

On top of things like an `Array` or `List<T>` this isn't such a problem, but when the implementation is on a query, or over a complex `yield return` structure or some other set of code (such as `Enumerable.Range`), it can *potentially* get expensive.

This is why ReSharper does things like warn you of multiple enumeration.

If you need to remember the results of `Count` use a variable. If you want to guard against enumerating an expensive source, you tend to do things like `var myCachedValues = myEnumerable.ToArray()` and then shift onto iterating the array instead (thereby guaranteeing only one iteration).

<sub>If you want to go down the silly route (like I did) you could implement an enumerator that internally caches things in a list so you get any benefits of deferred execution and also the benefits of caching once iterated at least once. I called it `IRepeatable`. I was largely berated by my colleagues for this, but I'm stubborn.</sub>

Comment: Why doesn't it get re-iterated right after the first projection `var data = items.Select(item => item * 2)`? Is there any caching taking place?

Comment: @avo `Select` is a deferrable method, so it will only iterate when you actually iterate the `data` enumerable. `Count` is not deferrable, as aren't most other aggregation-style methods (`All`, `Sum`, `GroupBy`, etc).

Answer (score 2):

`Enumerable.Range` (together with the rest of the pipeline) is enumerated once for each time you materialize the result. Your code makes two calls to `Count`, so you get two enumerations.

Comment: This is not so. If I follow you right, there should be three re-itertions: one for the initial `Enumerable.Range().Select()`, and one per each `data.Count()`, correct?

Comment: @avo, No not correct, the first `Select` doesn't force an iteration, it is deferrable. In fact, that projection is iterated when you call `Count` both times.

Comment: @avo: Basically you get an enumeration every time you ask about the results. `Select` doesn't ask about the results on the spot, it just says "...and then, for each result you get, convert it to something else".

Answer (score 1):

Because of deferred execution, so if you want to execute only once, change the line

```
var data = items.Select(item => item * 2);
```

to

```
 var data = items.Select(item => item * 2).ToList();
```